# Proper Way to write to shared memory Windows

Tags: c, winapi, memory

I have 2 processes, 1 process needs to write to a shared memory segment, the other process needs to read from the shared memory segment. The writing process only writes to shared mem, the reading process only reads.

Writing process

```
HANDLE hMapFile;
LPCTSTR pBuf;
char* Message = "test";
int MessageSize = 5;

hMapFile = CreateFileMappingA(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, 0, Size, SegmentName);
if (hMapFile == NULL)
{
    printf("Could not create file mapping object (%d).\n", GetLastError());

    return NULL;
}

pBuf = (LPTSTR)MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, Size);
if (pBuf == NULL)
{

    printf("Could not map view of file (%d).\n", GetLastError());

    //CloseHandle(hMapFile);

    return NULL;
}

CopyMemory((PVOID)pBuf, Message, MessageSize);
```

Shortly after my reading process will read the message like so

```
HANDLE hMapFile;
LPCTSTR pBuf;

hMapFile = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, SegmentName);
if (hMapFile == NULL)
{
    printf("Could not open file mapping object MINER PROC (%d).\n", GetLastError());

    exit(0);
    //return RetVal;
}

RetVal = (LPTSTR)MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, Size);

if (RetVal == NULL)
{
    printf("Could not map view of file (%d).\n", GetLastError());

    CloseHandle(hMapFile);

    exit(0);

    //return RetVal;
}

UnmapViewOfFile(hMapFile);

CloseHandle(hMapFile);
```

This works perfectly for a 1 time write then read. I need the writing process to be able to change the values.

I've tried this in the writing process

```
  memset((PVOID)pBuf, '\0', strlen(OriginalMessage));

  CopyMemory(pBuf, "newmessage",
             strlen("newmessage") + 1);
```

But this gives me random crashes in the writing process, although the reading process seems to be able to read the changes fine.

I've also tried to close the segment like this from the writing process immediately after CopyMemory() call

```
UnmapViewOfFile(pBuf);

CloseHandle(hMapFile);
```

But then the memory disappears and the reading process cannot read the segment name. I also tried calling UnmapViewOfFile() & CloseHandle() then creating a new memory segment with the same name and I keep getting random crashes after that.

What is the proper way to change a shared memory value of a given shared memory segment name without crashes? Thanks.

EDIT - I'd like to add that I tested this code using the described methods (creating new shared memory segments) on 4 Win10 machine, 2 Win7 machines and I got no crashes. The crashes only occur on a Win8.1 machine. it's quite odd.

EDIT2 - also, all functions are successful in both the reading and writing processes when the crash occurs.

Comment: There is rather a lot wrong.  You can't use a string type that depends on a compiler setting.  The code assumes it is a string but it is not, it is not properly zero-terminated.  Shared memory is a very low-level primitive, additional synchronization is required to ensure that a process reads the memory at the correct time, after it was written and ensuring that the other process cannot change it while reading it.  If the data needs to survive past program exit then a file is required.  Consider a named pipe, also uses shared memory but much easier to use.

Comment: Thanks for your help. No data need survive past program exit. The writing process will write to shared memory, then call the reading process via CreateProcess. The reading process will read the shared memory in the first lines in main(), then wait to be killed. So it's a very simple protocol, the writing process writes 1 time, the reading process reads 1 time, then waits to be terminated, and called again. So I really don't think this is a synchronization issue as they aren't reading/writing at the same time. I've edited the code to be CopyMemory(strlen()+1)

Comment: Which is what I assume you are referring to in your reference of improperly terminated strings. Could you please inform me on what else is wrong with the code? Thanks.

Comment: I've tried changing the CopyMemory(.., strlen()+1) and the crash still happens. While a bug, I don't think that causes the crash in the writing process because as long as enough memory is allocated in the CreateFileMapping() call it's ok for the writing process. Am very interested to hear what else is wrong with the code, thanks.

Comment: If you need to continuously communicate from one process to another, a shared memory segment is probably the most inappropriate tool. Use a (named) pipe, and have the system deal with the intricacies of synchronizing access, and notifying the recipient, as new data arrives.

Comment: It's not continuous though, it's a one time write and one time read, process gets terminated, repeat. It's so a process can receive config values. The code I pasted above is pretty much copy/pasted from MSDN. I'd like to get this working to avoid having to change my codebase.

Comment: It would be helpful to include details of the crash.  Also, try compiling with a higher warning level.

Comment: @Memq: the "one time read, one time write for configuration" case seems best suited for stdin redirection, a named pipe or even plain temporary file + command line arguments. You don't want to open the shared memory can of worms for this kind of problem.

Comment: I think what happens is novice programmers learn to use memory for many tasks and then believe it's the solution for all tasks. Shared memory is surely the wrong solution for your problem.

Comment: *random crashes* - more concrete ? and why you think that this related to shared section ? `memset((PVOID)pBuf, '\0', strlen(OriginalMessage));` - what sense in this ? i already not say about - what is `OriginalMessage`

Comment: UnmapViewOfFile doesn't take the handle to the file mapping, it takes the address it mapped to (that is, the return value from MapViewOfFile).

Comment: If you just need to pass data to a child process, why aren't you using command line parameters?